# Count Function Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I'm trying to use a count function in qlikview to count the number of "Past Due" projects. The past due projects are indicated by a 1 in my table. This is what I have which is not working.  Count({} Past Due}Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `count({<[Past Due]={1}>}distinct ProjectID)` or similar depending on what your unique ID is for a project. That filters to the data associated with [Past Due] being 1 and then counts the distinct ProjectIDs.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This worked once I loaded the calculated field into my table using the script editor.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped - feel free to mark that as the right answer if you think it is!